# Using CSS3 transforms to flip (rotate and scale) a block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to div boxes:

```
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="back"></div>
```

I then have CSS like so:

```
.back:hover {
    transform: scale(2) rotateX(0deg);
}

.front:hover {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) scale(1);
}
```

So I need the transform to flip the divs which it does fine on its own. But how do I scale it to 2x after the flip?

Comment: seems like you are looking for `animation` css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest keyframes

```
@keyframes scaleUp {
    50%{
        Transform: scale(2) rotate(0);
    }
    100%{
        Transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    }
}
.front {
    animation: scaleUp 1s forwards;
}
```

Or atleast something in that direction

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m2ukt404/ Here's a working example of keyframes although it's animation is run on start.