# Using CSS and JQuery to animate a hexagon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I created a CSS hexagon using 3 divs and border colors and sizes.  I would like to animate that hexagon by flipping it on it's x-axis and getting a new css hexagon like my code, below.

That all works in CSS. But then I want the new div to scale to 2x after the flip.

The CSS transform property does everything at once so I'm trying to scale after that using jQuery animate. If possible I would be open to doing everything in jQuery.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hexagons {
  width: 1100px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hexagon-holder {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 21.5px;
  width: 226px;
  height: 130.48px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 226px;
  height: 130.48px;
  background-image: url(http://csshexagon.com/img/meow.jpg);
  background-size: auto 258.6529px;
  background-position: center;
  border-left: solid 1px #333333;
  border-right: solid 1px #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hexagon .hexTop,
.hexagon .hexBottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 159.81px;
  height: 159.81px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background: inherit;
  left: 32.10px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
}
/*counter transform the bg image on the caps*/

.hexagon .hexTop:after,
.hexagon .hexBottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 224.0000px;
  height: 129.32646029847618px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-64.6632px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-64.6632px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-64.6632px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: inherit;
}
.hexagon .hexTop {
  top: -79.9031px;
  border-top: solid 1.4142px #333333;
  border-right: solid 1.4142px #333333;
}
.hexagon .hexTop:after {
  background-position: center top;
}
.hexagon .hexBottom {
  bottom: -79.9031px;
  border-bottom: solid 1.4142px #333333;
  border-left: solid 1.4142px #333333;
}
.hexagon .hexBottom:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5774px;
  left: 0;
  width: 224.0000px;
  height: 129.3265px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
.hexagon:nth-child(7n-2) {
  margin-left: 156px;
}
.hexagon:nth-child(n+5) {
  margin-top: 29px;
}
.hexText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 226px;
  height: 280.48px !important;
  background: transparent;
}
/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 226px;
  height: auto;
}
/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
/* 
 Some vertical flip updates 
*/

.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
}
.vertical .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.hexagon-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 226px;
  height: 130.48px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: teal;
  background-size: auto 247.1059px;
  background-position: center;
  border-left: solid 6px #333333;
  border-right: solid 6px #333333;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexTop,
.hexagon-overlay .hexBottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 159.81px;
  height: 159.81px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background: inherit;
  left: 27.10px;
}
/*counter transform the bg image on the caps*/

.hexagon-overlay .hexTop:after,
.hexagon-overlay .hexBottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 214.0000px;
  height: 123.55295760657991px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-61.7765px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-61.7765px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-61.7765px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: inherit;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexTop {
  top: -79.9031px;
  border-top: solid 8.4853px #333333;
  border-right: solid 8.4853px #333333;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexTop:after {
  background-position: center top;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexBottom {
  bottom: -79.9031px;
  border-bottom: solid 8.4853px #333333;
  border-left: solid 8.4853px #333333;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexBottom:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
.hexagon-overlay .hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.4641px;
  left: 0;
  width: 214.0000px;
  height: 123.5530px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagons">
  <div class="hexagon-holder flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">>
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="hexagon">
          <div class="hexTop"></div>
          <div class="hexBottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="hexagon-overlay">
          <div class="hexTop"></div>
          <div class="hexBottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hexText">LifePoint Dental
          <br />+</div>
        <div class="hexagon" style="transform:scaleX(-1);">
          <div class="hexTop"></div>
          <div class="hexBottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lektro/pen/eCgrc)

Comment: The css flip code: 

https://codepen.io/lektro/pen/eCgrc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS3 transforms to flip (rotate and scale) a block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234329/using-css3-transforms-to-flip-rotate-and-scale-a-block)

Comment: What I would suggest doing is setting up a keyframe animation in CSS3. Then you can have more control over what happens when.

Comment: Why would you want to use jquery if its possible in css?

Comment: I tried with css animations but trying again. I couldn't get it to behave correctly the first few times.